# detect google chrome web app in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I went through google and stackoverflow but none of the work arounds helps me to detect i njavascript whether my web application running inside google Google chrome web app or browser ? Thank you very much for taking timeout and suggestions. Thanks.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome browser you can use

```
navigator.userAgent
```

This will return:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36"

While "Chrome Web App" will return nothing (you can use `chrome.browser` API to communicate with browser)

Hope this helps.

Comment: no. it didn't work. in chrome web app also it gave me Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36.